# Non interactive setup rsyslog-mysql

Tags: 14.04, apt, system-installation

I am trying to setup non-interactive installation of rsyslog-mysql, but the process takes me to dbconfig-common and prompts me to answer several questions.

Is there a way to pre answer all the questions before doing:

`apt-get -y install rsyslog-mysql`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a setup script that uses `debconf-get-selections` and `debconf-set-selections` to answer the questions asked during installation:

1. Run the following:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y debconf-utils
   echo '#!/bin/sh' > setup.sh
   chmod +x setup.sh
   echo 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y debconf-utils' >> setup.sh
   echo "debconf-set-selections << 'END'" >> setup.sh
   ```
2. Install the software on one computer, answering the prompts as you want them to be answered on other computers.
3. For each package that asks questions during the installation, run the following, replacing `[package]` with the package name:

   ```
   sudo debconf-get-selections | fgrep [package] >> setup.sh
   ```
4. Run the following:

   ```
   echo 'END' >> setup.sh
   ```
5. Run the following, replacing `[package]` with the main package name (in your question `rsyslog-mysql`):

   ```
   echo 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y [package]' >> setup.sh
   ```
6. Copy `setup.sh` to another computer
7. Run `sudo ./setup.sh` on another computer to install the software without prompts.